# Save d3 tree state to localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, local-storage

I've made a collapsible tree layout with d3.js, in which users can click to expand and collapse branches. If users leave the page after expanding some branches and come back to the page later, the chart should be in the same state as when they left.

Right now, I've got a click function that flags a clicked node as `open` or `closed` (or it's undefined if it hasn't yet been clicked):

```js
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  // toggle node state
  if (d.state === undefined || d.state == "closed") {
    d.state = "open";
  } else {
    d.state = "closed";
  }
  update(d);
}
```

This works quite nicely and it's simple.

My idea is to update the JSON dataset I'm using with this new information and write that to localStorage, checking for it first each time the user comes to the page and then virtually clicking all the nodes flagged as "open" (not sure how to do it otherwise).

But the question is, **how** do I rewrite the JSON dataset with this new node information, or is there a better approach than what I've outlined above?

Please note that the actual putting to and getting from localStorage is not the problem; I know how to do that. It's specifically how to get the current state of the tree back into a new/revised dataset that the script can read again later when the user returns to the page.

Comment: Given that you can really only store key-value pairs, I would save the ID of the node and whether it's expanded or not.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff looks like you're the go-to d3 person here :). Do you think that I can then get that id and state, then d3.select() that node and call click() on it? Would that be sufficient? (Only one branch is ever open at one time)

Comment: I would do it the other way round -- iterate over all nodes and check whether they're open. You can of course do it your way as well, that would also be more efficient for large trees.

Comment: It's a large tree. Quite large, in fact, which is why the state is so important. Wouldn't want someone to have to traverse again unless they choose to.

Comment: Ok, so you get the IDs of the open nodes from local storage and then select those nodes (e.g. the ID could correspond to the DOM ID) and do whatever you have to do to expand them.